# openCV and filenames in python

Tags: python, opencv

anybody familiar with openCV know how to make it so the output is a different file each time. OR how to make it so the video appends to the original one.

here is the code I am working with

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import cv2
import numpy as np
import datetime
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.IN)
import os
# Setup the camera such that it closes
# when we are done with it.

os.chdir ("/home/pi/Videos")
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
while True:
        if GPIO.input(11) == 1:
                filename = datetime.datetime.now() .strftime ("%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%$
                print("about to record")
                out = cv2.VideoWriter('video.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))
                ret, frame = cap.read()
                if ret==True:
                        out.appendleft(frame)
                        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
                        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q') or GPIO.input(11) $
                                break
                else:

                        break
        else:
                break
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

thanks in advance for any and all help!

Comment: Please, fix up the code in the sample, so it doesn't contain syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will store data in a progressive filename system

```
from os  import path

def open_next_file(someData, template='incomingVideo{}.jpg'):
    """Creates a new file for storing new Firmware."""

    ## Store upto 100 file names 
    for serial in range(100):
        if not path.exists(template.format(serial)):
            ## if file does not exist,
            ## enter data into the new file

            with open(template.format(serial), 'wb+') as f:
                f.write(someData)
            break

        else:
            ## if file already exists then,
            ## don't write on existing files
            pass

    return template.format(serial)
```

you can call this function everytime you want to write a new data to a new file viz. `incomingVideo1.jpg` or `incomingVideo2.jpg`

You can change the parameters according your needs.

#### Example

```
newFile = open_next_file(someDat="Write this inside")
print(newFile)
```

gives result as `incomingVideoX.jpg` where x depends on `range()` function in the loop

Comment: wow thanks for the thorough response. I should of mentioned I am a newb to coding and a lot of this goes over my head. I understand IF statements and while loops etc.. so i guess i have a lot of learning to do. I am currently in a coding class so maybe ill ask there.

Comment: @Daveyman123 thanks. Don't forget to accept the answer if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: im getting the error that path is not defined. I am using python 2.7 btw

Comment: Add the following on top `from os import path` I will add it to the answer too for future reference

Comment: whenever i call the function inside my while loop it simply creates a bunch of new files. How do i make it so it records for a bit and then stops and saves just to one new file

Comment: That is a bit tricky. Maybe use the `time` module in python create a `start` and `stop` stamp and then use `break` whenever you wish to stop the data to be written. However try finding the answer here as I am not much sure of OpenCV in general

Comment: I seem to have found a solution by using another while loop to record video while keeping the call function (calling the function you made) outside the while loop. Thank you so very much Shan-Desai!!